# Save Google image as map with a point location dropped on it using a coordinate

Tags: coordinates, image, maps

I have saved a Google map image (PNG) using coordinates in Python. Now, I want to mark a location(as a coloured dot) of that coordinate on the map and save the same image. Are there any options available for that?

Here is the code-

```
import urllib
from django import image
import os
import math
class GoogleMapDownloader:
"""
    A class which generates high resolution google maps images given
    a longitude, latitude and zoom level
"""

def __init__(self, lat, lng, zoom=12):
    """
        GoogleMapDownloader Constructor
        Args:
            lat:    The latitude of the location required
            lng:    The longitude of the location required
            zoom:   The zoom level of the location required, ranges from 0 - 23
                    defaults to 12
    """
    self._lat = lat
    self._lng = lng
    self._zoom = zoom

def getXY(self):
    """
        Generates an X,Y tile coordinate based on the latitude, longitude 
        and zoom level
        Returns:    An X,Y tile coordinate
    """
    
    tile_size = 256

    # Use a left shift to get the power of 2
    # i.e. a zoom level of 2 will have 2^2 = 4 tiles
    numTiles = 1 << self._zoom

    # Find the x_point given the longitude
    point_x = (tile_size/ 2 + self._lng * tile_size / 360.0) * numTiles // tile_size

    # Convert the latitude to radians and take the sine
    sin_y = math.sin(self._lat * (math.pi / 180.0))

    # Calulate the y coorindate
    point_y = ((tile_size / 2) + 0.5 * math.log((1+sin_y)/(1-sin_y)) * -(tile_size / (2 * math.pi))) * numTiles // tile_size

    return int(point_x), int(point_y)

def generateImage(self, **kwargs):
    """
        Generates an image by stitching a number of google map tiles together.
        
        Args:
            start_x:        The top-left x-tile coordinate
            start_y:        The top-left y-tile coordinate
            tile_width:     The number of tiles wide the image should be -
                            defaults to 5
            tile_height:    The number of tiles high the image should be -
                            defaults to 5
        Returns:
            A high-resolution Goole Map image.
    """

    start_x = kwargs.get('start_x', None)
    start_y = kwargs.get('start_y', None)
    tile_width = kwargs.get('tile_width', 5)
    tile_height = kwargs.get('tile_height', 5)

    # Check that we have x and y tile coordinates
    if start_x == None or start_y == None :
        start_x, start_y = self.getXY()

    # Determine the size of the image
    width, height = 256 * tile_width, 256 * tile_height

    #Create a new image of the size require
    map_img = Image.new('RGB', (width,height))

    for x in range(0, tile_width):
        for y in range(0, tile_height) :
            url = 'https://mt0.google.com/vt?x='+str(start_x+x)+'&y='+str(start_y+y)+'&z='+str(self._zoom)

            current_tile = str(x)+'-'+str(y)
            urllib.urlretrieve(url, current_tile)
        
            im = Image.open(current_tile)
            map_img.paste(im, (x*256, y*256))
          
            os.remove(current_tile)

    return map_img

def main():
# Create a new instance of GoogleMap Downloader
gmd = GoogleMapDownloader(51.5171, 0.1062, 13)

print("The tile coorindates are {}".format(gmd.getXY()))

try:
    # Get the high resolution image
    img = gmd.generateImage()
except IOError:
    print("Could not generate the image - try adjusting the zoom level and checking your coordinates")
else:
    #Save the image to disk
    img.save("high_resolution_image.png")
    print("The map has successfully been created")


if __name__ == '__main__':  main()
```